# number of pairs - combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics

if I want to know the number of pairs in a group of 2n elements
what is the difference between:

a. ${2n}\choose{2}$

b. $\frac{(2n)!}{2!^n\cdot n!}$

c.${2n}\choose{2}$ ${2n-2}\choose{2}$... ${2}\choose{2}$

I do not understand the differences between these options,
many thanks.

Comment: More clarity about what is to be counted is needed.  Are these "pairs" ordered or unordered?  Are you trying to *partition* the set of $2n$ elements into (disjoint) pairs?  Does the order of the pairs (in such a partition) make a difference?  These kinds of variations can lead to different counts (and hence to different expressions).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example, let $n=6$

a) counts the number of ways in which you can choose two elements out of $2n$.

Here, we are counting the list:  $\{1,2\}, \{1,3\}, \{1,4\}, \{1,5\}, \{1,6\}, \{2,3\}, \{2,4\},\dots$

It answers a question such as "You have $2n$ people in a class.  How many possible ways can you choose two of them to be co-class presidents?"  Note how we are only having chosen a total of two people overall here.  Also notice how it doesn't matter which person was "first" versus "second."  They are co-class presidents.  Not one president and one vice president.

---

b) counts the number of ways in which you can partition the set of $2n$ elements into $n$ *unlabeled* parts each of which of size two.

Here, we are counting the list: $\{\{1,2\},\{3,4\},\{5,6\}\}, \{\{1,2\},\{3,5\},\{4,6\}\}, \{\{1,2\},\{3,6\},\{4,5\}\}, \{\{1,3\},\{2,4\},\{5,6\}\},\dots$

It answers a question such as "You have $2n$ people in a class.  How many ways can they pair up to have each group work on the same project?"  Here, notice that our pairs aren't named or distinguishable in any way except by who is in it.  We don't care if Billy and his friend sit on the left of the room to work on their assignment or the right side of the room.  All we care about is who Billy's partner happened to be and similarly how each other person was partnered, etc...

---

c) counts the number of ways in which you can partition the set of $2n$ elements into $n$ *unlabeled parts* each of which of size two

$(\{1,2\},\{3,4\},\{5,6\}), (\{1,2\},\{3,5\},\{4,6\}), (\{1,2\},\{3,6\},\{4,5\}), (\{1,2\},\{4,5\},\{3,6\}),\dots$

It answers a question such as "You have $2n$ people in a class.  You have $n$ different tasks you want accomplished.  In how many possible ways can you assign different pairs of students to these different tasks where each student gets assigned to exactly one task each?"  For example, you assign two students to be co-class presidents, two students to clean the chalkboard, two students to take out the trash, two students to feed the class hamster, etc...  Unlike the first problem, we are needing to think about choosing more than just two students in total.  Unlike the second problem, it matters where each pair was assigned.

Note in particular the difference in connotation between using curly brackets $\{~\}$ and parentheses $(~)$.  We consider order relevant within parentheses but not relevant within curly brackets.  In particular, you have $\{\{1,2\},\{3,4\},\{5,6\}\}$ is equivalent to $\{\{3,4\},\{1,2\},\{6,5\}\}$ for instance however $(\{1,2\},\{3,4\},\{5,6\})$ is not equivalent to $(\{3,4\},\{1,2\},\{6,5\})$